# Oracle GRCC Tcg data type issue

Tags: java, tomcat, oracle-apps, oracleapplications, oracle-application-server

I am working with oracle GRCC Tcg Application version 8.6.4. I have created business object successfully on this Tcg application. After that I have created a model using that business object. While I'm trying to save the model, the following exception arises.

Please help me to clear the exception.

```
ModelServiceImpl:1262 Validating Model Query ...Supplier Test
2012-10-29 15:34:21,843 ERROR [http-8080-3] ModelAdapter:1485 Value 100.0 is of the data type class java.lang.Double, but should be of data type [DataType: java.lang.Integer Size: 4]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 100.0 is of the data type class java.lang.Double, but should be of data type [DataType: java.lang.Integer Size: 4]
        at oracle.apps.grc.common.filter.argument.LiteralArgument.setValue(LiteralArgument.java:152)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.createBinaryFilter(ModelAdapter.java:2654)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.toAbstractFilter(ModelAdapter.java:2524)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.traverseTree(ModelAdapter.java:1639)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.populateModelQuery(ModelAdapter.java:1479)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.populateModelQuery(ModelAdapter.java:1438)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.workbench.server.ModelServiceImpl.validateModelQuery(ModelServiceImpl.java:1295)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.common.server.context.AACGRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(AACGRemoteServiceServlet.java:69)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.webapp.servlet.ApplicationResourceRequestFilter.doFilter(ApplicationResourceRequestFilter.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-10-29 15:34:21,994 DEBUG [http-8080-3] ModelServiceImpl:465 ModelServiceImpl.saveModel(ModelPOJO pModel) : Entering Save Model
2012-10-29 15:34:22,029 ERROR [http-8080-3] ModelAdapter:1485 Value 100.0 is of the data type class java.lang.Double, but should be of data type [DataType: java.lang.Integer Size: 4]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 100.0 is of the data type class java.lang.Double, but should be of data type [DataType: java.lang.Integer Size: 4]
        at oracle.apps.grc.common.filter.argument.LiteralArgument.setValue(LiteralArgument.java:152)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.createBinaryFilter(ModelAdapter.java:2654)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.toAbstractFilter(ModelAdapter.java:2524)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.traverseTree(ModelAdapter.java:1639)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.populateModelQuery(ModelAdapter.java:1479)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.populateModelQuery(ModelAdapter.java:1438)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.widget.server.grccmodel.adapters.ModelAdapter.domainModelForDS(ModelAdapter.java:1075)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.workbench.server.ModelServiceImpl.saveModel(ModelServiceImpl.java:494)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.common.server.context.AACGRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(AACGRemoteServiceServlet.java:69)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at oracle.apps.grc.ui.webapp.servlet.ApplicationResourceRequestFilter.doFilter(ApplicationResourceRequestFilter.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


Thank you in advance..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem will solved.it just an tomcat error.i just restarted my tomcat server the exception will be gone..